# How to update an object stored in Realm using React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

Recently I keep running into several problems when trying to write data to my realm instance. The error I keep running into is the following:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Cannot modify
>   managed objects outside of a write transaction.

Despite my "changes" being done within a write transaction. I've looked at the [official docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#writes) of Realm for doing writes. But it keeps running into the message above. So things I tried in order to write to solve this issue:

1. update to the latest version of the library in my project I now am at 6.0.2
2. Using the solution below:

> ```
> Realm.open({
>    path: 'database.realm',
>    schema: this.modelSchema,
>    schemaVersion: 3,
>  }).then(realm => {
>    realm.write(() => {
>      realm.create('RouteType', {typeID: element.typeID, isSelected: !element.isSelected}, true);
>    });
>  });
> ```

And another method I used with the same result is this one:

```
try {
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create(
      'RouteType',
      {typeID: element.typeID, isSelected: !element.isSelected}, true,);
   });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```